# Can't log the response however I can see it in Postman and network tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am doing register with an endpoint for it. The problem now is handling validation when it comes from backend. That means when I send a username less than 6 letters backend respondes to that saying username should be more than 6 letters.

Now, the response from backend shows inside network tab, and shows in postman but when I do `console.log(response)` it shows an error saying `referenceError: response is not defined`.

My code

```
 axios.post(url, payload,{
                })
            .then( response => {

                console.log('response')
                console.log(response)
            } )
```

[image: Response from network tab]

[image: response from postman]

[image: Response in console]

Comment: Sometimes when the status of the response starts with 4XX or 5XX, it is considered an error for some frameworks. Check if the `post` method has a second parameter for the error response (maybe a second parameter in the callback or the second callback).

Comment: its also suspicious that you have an error because you try not to access a member of response but console.log it. It should just log undefined in that case. Your error hints that you try to do `response.something`, only then you would see that error. Maybe adding a catch block wouldnt be half bad either. I suggest showing more/full code.

Comment: There's absolutely no way that code could result in that error. I assume the code you posted was simplified from your actual code for the sake of this question but you clearly left out some important parts.

Comment: No it is the same code

Comment: Sorry but that's simply not possible. There's no way your `console.log(response)` would throw the error "ReferenceError: response is not defined" when `response` is clearly defined in the function signature three lines above.

Answer (score 0):

According the axios docs when response status is out of 2xx you must use `catch` block. [see](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

Comment: But then why does the `then` block even run? should it not straight up error and never run that block?

Comment: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('no good')).then(console.log)` returns this `Uncaught (in promise) no good`

Comment: I guess thats why, "Axios fulfills the request promise when the server responds with an HTTP success code, or rejects the request promise when the server responds with an HTTP error. If an error occurs, you can handle the error with .then() or .catch()."  https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/then

Answer (score 0):

The `then` block is not executing because the `4xx` status codes are considered errors. Axios then throws an exception which you need to catch. To handle the `4xx` cases you can use a [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) block, which will execute whenever there is an error with your Axios request.

Comment: What does this add to the question? This has been said already in the other answer. Also the error suggests that the then block is in fact executed. Otherwise where would it try to access the response and throw that error?